# how to shutdown wince r2 device when i click on button

Tags: windows-ce

how  to shutdown wince r2 device  when i click on button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, and on a great many things.

First, what button, exactly?  If it's a hardware button, then it's going to likely require capturing an interrupt, but that's going to be up to the OEM, so talk with them.

If you mean a software button, then you can probably just call [GwesPowerOffSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms902923.aspx), or alternately call [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa928103.aspx) with VK_OFF.  THis assumes that the OS on the hardware supports Suspend (not all CE devices do, and not all that do implement it through the power manager).

Of course this assumes that by "shut down" you mean tell the power manager to put the device into Suspend mode.  If you mean something else (like turning off a power supply or something), then it's going to be OEM-specific and again, you'll need to ask the OEM how to do it with their device.